# shrink specific class with proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to remove some classes form building.
I mentioned in proguard to skip shrinking all classes extended from View class, but now I want to shrink some classes extended form View class. 
My question is: how can I shrink some classes extended from View class , at the same time not removing condition to shrink all View extended classes ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
-keep class !mypackage.ShrinkMe1, !mypackage.ShrinkMe2 extends android.view.View
```